# Selenium looking for the getAllFields() function

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have seen in a lot of places that to get an array or list of id in selenium you use the `getAllFields or` something like that but that function is in what part webdriver, webelement, the only thing i see is that everybody says use `selenium.getAllFields()`.
and as i was saying I don't know what is element is selenium in the that function
by the way im not asking what is selenium but rather how to get the `getAllFields()` function im using java to do the test
thanks in advance

Comment: I upvoted it, still dont get why someone downvoted it, it's true that everywhere getallfields() is called over selenium.getAllFields()

Answer (score 2):

To do `getAllFields()` you need to do

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
```

The list of elements returned should give you want and you can use them how you want